# How to inject certificates to IAAS or PAAS vms on Azure?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services, azure-keyvault

I know its possible to inject certificates to PAAS worker roles in azure.
In below video at time 0:31:00 talks about injecting service certificates to IAAS and PAAS both. Is it possible for IAAS linux and windows vms?

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/videos/episode-169-azure-key-vault-with-sumedh-barde/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

For VMs that you create through the Azure Resource Manager, use these steps: http://blogs.technet.com/b/kv/archive/2015/07/14/vm_2d00_certificates.aspx

For legacy VMs, use the same steps as you do for PaaS worker roles. They are clubbed together as "cloud services".

Sumedh